# Расположение элемента в центре экрана

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как расположить блок точно в середине экрана,по горизонтали можно через margin : 0 auto, а как сделать по вертикали?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариантов масса.
 1. С помощью line-height
 2. Абсолютным позиционированием
 3. С помощью padding
 4. С помощью таблиц
 5. С помощью flexbox
 6. С помощью transform
 7. С применением отрицательного margin-top
 8. С помощью псевдоэлемента :before
 Выбирайте любой, какой вам больше нравится.

Выравнивание с помощью :before :
*Данный способ работает только если внутренний блок не имеет абсолютного позиционирования.*

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  // другие стили для блока-родителя
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
}
.wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  // другие стили для внутреннего блока
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Буду очень благодарен если распишите как сделать ток через  :before , и pading.Но спасибо и на этом!

Comment: Дописал с :before.
С отступами можно использовать если вам известны высоты обоих блоков .wrapper {height: 100px; text-align: center;} .inner {height: 50px;
margin: 25px 0;}

Comment: @Alex лучше добавить `height` для `.wrapper`, чтобы в примере при выполнении кода было видно выравнивание посредине блока, т.к. сейчас в примере визуально не видно, что блок выравнивается посредине `.wrapper`.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать flex свойство, а можно так:

```css
.par {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.ch {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="par"><div class="ch"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно так через `flexbox`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
#cont {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
#cont div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div id='cont'>
  <div></div>
</div>
```